# "Spurious disk" detection with ComponentMeasurements

Tags: image-processing

Using this code a third "spurious" disk is detected.

```
fig = Rasterize[Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], White,
     Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.1], Disk[{0.75, 0.75}, 0.05]}],
   ImageResolution -> 25];
data = ComponentMeasurements[fig, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]
Show[fig,
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]]}] & /@ data[[;; , 2]]
 ]
```

Quite weird since it arises from a completely black region.

Any comments?

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, I get a slightly different result (OS X): http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lb8L.png  I see this in all versions since 9.0.1.

Comment: I am using version 10.1. If you go for ellipsis detection it is not giving that.

Answer (score 16):

This happens because:

- The region is not completely black.  It has a white margin.
- As I understand, `EquivalentDiskRadius` does not detect a disk. It takes every component, regardless of shape, and constructs a disk of the same area.

The third circle is in the middle of the white image border, but it is much smaller than it as it must match the area of white pixels.

Why is there a white border?

First, notice that `fig` is not an `Image`.  It is a `Graphics`.  When you apply an image processing function, it automatically gets converted to an `Image`.  Let us avoid this and create the `Image` directly using

```
Rasterize[..., "Image"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's easier to see if we invert the image, but you can also see if if you just click it in the notebook and observe the orange border.

What can we do to fix this?

First of all, to set the background of a `Graphics`, use the `Background` option instead of placing a rectangle in the background.  Graphics have padding and a margin too.

This is what we get if we try it:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is still a white line at the bottom.  This is likely due to rounding things to integer pixel dimensions.  The white comes from the `DefaultStyleDefinitions` of the front end.  To fix this, we must set the *rasterization background*, not the graphics background.  If we do this, we might as well remove `Background` from within `Graphics`.  Now it's good:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To sum up, we needed to:

- Make sure that `Rasterize` creates an `Image`
- Set the rasterization background (normally inherited determined by front end settings) to black.

Final code:

```
fig = Rasterize[
  Graphics[{White, Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.1], Disk[{0.75, 0.75}, 0.05]}], 
  "Image", ImageResolution -> 25, Background -> Black]

data = ComponentMeasurements[fig, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]
Show[fig, Graphics[{Red, Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]]}] & /@ data[[;; , 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might notice that above the red circles appear shifted relative to the white disks.  This is just a rendering artefact again due to rounding to integer screen pixels.  In reality there is no shift, this becomes clear when magnifying the figure.

Comment: Oh yeah, Thanks.

Comment: (+1) I have one correction: the `Background` is inherited not from the styles of the `EvaluationNotebook[]` but seemingly from the global `DefaultStyleDefinitions` accessible from `Options[$FrontEndSession, DefaultStyleDefinitions]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for the correction!

Comment: A truly outstanding answer. I enjoyed reading it and learned a few new things in the process.Thank you! (+1, obviously)